# Realm React Native - How to assign object property types

Tags: react-native, realm

I have 2 realm data models. 'Foods' model has a object property type 'foodRating' which is intended to be a link to the FoodsRatings model.

```
class FoodRatings extends Realm.Object {}
FoodRatings.schema = {
  name: 'FoodRatings',
  primaryKey: 'foodRatingId',
  properties: {
    foodRatingId: { type: 'int', indexed: true },
    name: 'string',
  }
}; 


class Foods extends Realm.Object {}
Foods.schema = {
  name: 'Foods',
  primaryKey: 'foodId',
  properties: {
    foodId: { type: 'int', indexed: true },
    name: 'string',
    foodRating: {type: 'FoodRatings'},
  }
};
```

FoodRatings is pre-populated with a number of rows that are intended to be static and unchanging. You assign a foodRating to a food from one of the options in FoodRatings.

The issue I am having is when I attempt to create a new Foods object and assign the 'foodRating' property a FoodRatings object, it breaks.

```
foodRatings = realm.objects('FoodRatings')
let foodRating = foodRatings.filtered('foodRatingId = 1');
realm.write(() => {
   realm.create('Foods', {foodId: 1, name: 'apples', foodRating: foodRating[0]});
})
```

I see a lot of talk about 'linking' for realm but it's yet to be released for realm js. All of the examples and documentation assume new entries rather than existing objects you are trying to assign to a model.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer first - I'm using Realm Swift and have never used Realm React Native.

Having said that, from the documentation, it looks like you have the definition of `foodRating` wrong. I would have throught it should be like the example

```
cars:    {type: 'list', objectType: 'Car'}
```

ie.

```
foodRating: {type: 'list', objectType: 'FoodRatings'}
```

"Linking" exists in Realm Swift, but in your case would probably be used to link back from a food ratings to all the foods that have that rating. So I think it solves a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

What error are you seeing exactly?

your example works for me

```js
realm.write(() => {
  realm.create('FoodRatings', {foodRatingId: 10, name: '1 star'});
  realm.create('FoodRatings', {foodRatingId: 20, name: '2 star'});
  realm.create('FoodRatings', {foodRatingId: 30, name: '3 star'});
});

let foodRatings = realm.objects('FoodRatings');
foodRating = foodRatings.filtered('foodRatingId = 10');
realm.write(() => {
   realm.create('Foods', {foodId: 1, name: 'apples', foodRating: foodRating[0]});
});

let foods = realm.objects('Foods');
console.log("foods[0]= " + foods[0].name );
```